# Can I constraint QML Map zoomlevel to be integer?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using QtLocation Map to display a map on desktop and using mouse wheel to zoom the map. Now I want to constraint the zoomlevel property to be only integers so that when I rotate the mouse wheel the map goes directly to the next integer zoomlevel(from 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 etc). Can someone help?

Comment: Not true, [Map.zoomLevel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#zoomLevel-prop) is real but you can pass your integer without any problem, it will be casted by QtQuick to real.

Comment: I know that Map.zoomLevel is of real type. That's why I am asking how to only allow it to have integeral values.

Comment: Hmm ... if you will pass integer value it will get it.  `Map.zoomLevel = yourIntererValue;`

Comment: I mean when I rotate the mouse wheel, it changes the value of zoomlevel right? But now the rotation of mouse wheel changes the zoom level gradually from 1 to 1.5 to 2. What I want is that when I rotate the mouse wheel, the zoom level changes from 1 to 2 directly without going to the intermediate real values.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be impossible if you want to use only qml, at least for me. Let's look why it is.
First thing I have tried is applying a simple rounding to `zoomLevel` property of the map object whenever `onZoomLevelChanged` is triggered.

```
Map {
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: mapPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
    zoomLevel: 14
    id: map

    onZoomLevelChanged: {
        map.zoomLevel = Math.round(zoomLevel)
        console.log(map.zoomLevel)
    }
}
```

However, since QML processes data so fast, you can't even change zoom level from its initial value, like whenever you move the mouse wheel whenever it changes from (such as) 14 to 14.0001 QML makes it again 14. So this way doesn't work.